# Como obter uma valor de uma propriedade da array?

Tags: php, laravel, array, mvc, cakephp

A VÁRIAVEL ARMAZENZA:

```
$parcelas = DB::select("SELECT parcela_number FROM parcelas WHERE 3000 BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max");
```

VAR_DUMP:

```
   array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#144 (1) {
    ["parcela_number"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

OBJETIVO:

```
$parcelas->parcela_number // RESULT 3
```

Comment: posta, por favor, o var_dump($parcelas); Daí eu consigo te ajudar

Comment: Ok, já postei o var_dump

Comment: ok tenta assim:
$parcelas[0]->parcela_number;

Me fala se deu certo, que daí te explico o porque etc

Comment: Deu certo, só que não entendi o porque, em outro caso semelhante funciona assim  $parcelas[0]->value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

André, vamos lá.

A ferramenta do var_dump() é muito interessante pois você compreende o tipo de retorno que você tem. Em seu retorno nós tivemos o seguinte:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#144 (1) {
    ["parcela_number"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

vc nota que a `$parcela` é um `array`. E depois temos um `objeto`. A maneira de acessar os dados de `array` e de um `objeto` são diferentes, por isso não estava conseguindo antes. E por ser um `array` não conseguimos acessar os dados via `->` e sim por posição (índice).

Faço um `foreach()` na sua variável `$parcelas` que conseguirá pegar os dados via `$parcela->`

Eu não consigo criar um código para você, pois necessito de mais código seu para te dar um exemplo prático, mas acredito que conseguirá tranquilamente.

Para resolução do seu problema faça: `$parcelas[0]->parcela_number;`

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação do Laravel( https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries ), o Fachada DB juntamente com o método select. Ex:

```
$resultados = DB::select('select * from ...')
```

SEMPRE retornará um array e caso haja resultado, será um objeto dentro deste array.

Desta forma, o acesso deverá ser a partir de um array.

```
$resultados[0]; // para acessar o primeiro resultado
```

ou ainda:

```
foreach($resultados as $resultado) {
    echo $resultado->key;
}
```

para acessar todos os resultados.

A saber: Métodos interessantes para debug dd() e dump() disponíveis no Laravel.